# PHP SESSION not working without cookies enabled

Tags: php, session, cookies

Ok, So The idea of the two scripts below is very simple.First, in `login.php`, we assign `$_SESSION['username']=$username` and then redirect the page to `index.php` where the script checks `if $_SESSION['username']` is set.If it is checked, then *Edit Profile* and *Log Out* option is shown and if it is not set, then Options like Login and signup is shown. But even if the form is filled correctly, then also it shows LogIn and signup options. It work with cookies enabled.But not if they are disabled.Here are the codes

---

`Login.php`

```
session_start();
.
.
.
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['password']=$password;
$location="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index.php";
header("Location:".$location."?".htmlspecialchars(SID));
}
```

---

`Index.php`

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION[SID.'username'])){
echo '&#10084;<a href="viewprofile.php">View Profile</a>'."<br>";
echo '&#10084;<a href="editprofile.php">Edit Profile</a>'."<br>";
echo '&#10084;<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>'."<br>";
}
else{
echo '&#10084;<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
echo '&#10084;<a href="signup.php">Signup</a>';
```

---

Now, when i have all `php.ini` settings correct and `use_cookie=0` and `trans_sid = 1`, then if i supply right info to `login.php`, `index.php` shows the else code block.Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a framework you haven't mentioned, I'd say your reference book has awful typos. I can't see any [PHP directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) called `trans_sid`. The closest that exists is session.use_trans_sid:

> **session.use_trans_sid** `boolean`
>       session.use_trans_sid whether transparent sid support is enabled or not. Defaults to 0 (disabled)

`use_cookie` does not exist either.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the official PHP documentation that supports your statement?

Comment: i just used for my convenience because i was was really frustrated.

Comment: But it's possible that PHP is not smart enough to figure out what you really meant. I suggest you use the exact documented names verbatim.

Comment: hmm...BTW, can you help me figure out whats the problem